# "I have been had it" or "I have had it": which one is correct?

Tags: present-perfect

Which one is correct?

> This is a very old book. I have been had it since I was child

or

> This is a very old book. I have had it since I was child

Comment: ".....I have had it since I was a child." is  correct.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct present perfect of "to have." "I have had it since I was a child," is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"I have had it" is the correct answer because the first one used "have been" and "had" in one phrase, which makes it grammatically wrong.

Comment: "I have been had", usually contracted to "I've been had", is a common expression that is not grammatically incorrect. (Not that it's remotely applicable to the OP's case.)

Answer (score 0):

The auxiliary verb "be" is usually followed by the present participle (as in "having") rather than the past participle (as in "had"). Thus, "I have been had it" is not a valid phrase. Even if you wrote "I have been having it", it would be wrong because "have" is a verb that expresses a state, not a repeated action (as in "I have been coughing all day"). By contrast, "I have had it", from your second example, is fine.